# <c:if> Tag does not reduce the component tree in composite components

Tags: jsf-2, jstl, composite-component, mojarra

We are developing an enterprise application with pretty large and complex views based on Mojarra 2.2.8. Our largest views produce JSF component trees of >20.000 nodes. Of coure we ran into performance issues, so we started to reduce the tree size by replacing `<ui:repeat>` with `<c:forEach>` and by replacing the `rendered` attribute with `<c:if>` blocks as recommended in this [very informative post by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense).
These measures reduced the component tree by a huge amount and brought significant improvements in performance.

One measure did not work out though: Our views contain severals tabs in a tab group. When we tried to remove contents of invisible tabs via `<c:if>` tags, the component tree of these tabs was still present and there was no benefit in performance.

We figured out, that the only difference between this usage of `<c:if>` and several other places was, that this time `<c:if>` was part of a composite component and its contents were injected through a `<composite:insertChildren/>` tag. The process of injecting the children of a composite component tag to its definition seems to somehow conflict with the `<c:if>` tag. We also tried to replace the `insertChildren` tag with a `facet` based approach, but the result remained the same.

To demonstrate this, here is a composite component, that wraps all its contents in a `<c:if>` tag, that always evaluates to `false`:

```
<composite:interface>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <c:if test="false"> 
        <composite:insertChildren />
    </c:if>
</composite:implementation>
```

This component shoud display nothing, even if it is used with a lot of child elements in a view. And it *does* display nothing but the component tree is *still there* and there is no performance benefit.

Unfortunately, this makes it impossible for us, to develop a performance optimized tab group composite component. Can anybody please explain, why this happens and if there is a way around it?

*We are on mojarra 2.2.8, el-api 2.2.5, tomcat 8.0.*

Comment: Tried a newer version? Tried myfaces? Just try, not saying to use in production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technical problem is that the `<c:if>` in this construct only prevents inclusion (and execution) of the `<cc:insertChildren>` tag itself. The `<cc:insertChildren>` in turn is actually responsible for **relocating** any composite component children to the declared place in the composite component implementation so that they will be actually rendered. By default, a composite component does not render any children. The declared children are actually stored as a facet of the composite component.

In other words, the `<c:if>` actually doesn't prevent those component children to end up in the component tree. It only prevents the `<cc:insertChildren>` from being invoked. The observed behavior is therefore working as designed. To achieve the desired behavior, you should actually be moving back the `<c:if>` to the client.

```
<your:composite ...>
    <c:if test="#{false}">
        ...
    </c:if>
</your:composite>
```

I understand that this is unintuitive. Actually, you should take a step back from using composite components to compose the template. They are not well suited for that. You should use `<ui:composition>`, `<ui:include>`, `<ui:decorate>` or tag files for that instead. Composite components should only be used to compose a component.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)